# How to translate menu items to the selected language - not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, navigation, menu, menu-item

I have a Sharepoint Online website. It's a modern site. I have enabled multilanguage settings on Site Settings > Language and added French and German as options.

I've set translations for my page content so once the user selects French or German it gets translated.

I also set translations for the top menu items, however they are not getting translated. As I troubleshoot further, I see they are based on user's own Office365 regional and language settings, so when I update my own settings to French for instance, I can see them in French with the given translations.

How can I set it based on SharePoint site's regional settings instead my own?

This is what I need:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/new-sharepoint-feature-multilingual-publishing-for-pages-and/ba-p/1432445

Followed each step same, working all fine except the top menu items are not getting translated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow what you want. The language of the navigation and interface follows your own profile settings, you report that is working correctly. You say that you want it to be based on the site's regional settings, by which I think you mean the site's language setting, but that doesn't make sense.  The site's base language doesn't change, so there is little point to entering translations.  Do you mean the content language dropdown in the top right?

[image: content language dropdown]

That isn't a feature of SharePoint.  If you've seen that, it may have been PointFire.